# Creating a hot observable and adding things to it

Tags: system.reactive

I am trying to create a hot observable where I can add stuff to it. Here's an outline of the basic class

```
public class MyObservable
{
    public IObservable<string> Stream;

    public MyObservable()
    {
         Observable.Create...?
    }

    public void AddString(string eventDescription)
    {
       //Add to Stream
    }
}
```

Somewhere else in the code I want to be able to do something like

```
var ob = new MyObservable();
MyObservable.Add("User created");
```

Then somewhere else something like:

```
ob.Stream.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

I am not really sure how I am supposed to add strings to the observable

edit: I've tried doing something like this, but I'm not sure if maybe I'm not doing things in the way it's supposed to be done

```
    private IObserver<string> _observer;

    public void Add(string e)
    {
        if(Stream == null) 
        { 
            Stream = Observable.Create<string>(
                (IObserver<string> observer) =>
                {
                    _observer = observer;
                    observer.OnNext(e);
                    return Disposable.Empty;
                });
        }
        else
        {
              _observer.OnNext(e);
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a little more reading on the contracts of [observables and observers](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)

Regardless, what you are looking for is a `Subject`, which implements both the `Observable` and `Observer` interfaces.

If you still want to wrap it it would look like so:

```
public class MyObservable
{
  private Subject<string> subject; 
  public IObservable<string> Stream 
  { 
    get { return this.subject.AsObservable();

  }

  public MyObservable()
  {
    subject = new Subject<string>();
  }

  public void AddString(string eventDescription)
  {
    //Add to Stream
    this.subject.OnNext(eventDescription);
  }
}
```

Comment: Then why does the documentation say subjects should never be used for anything other than testing purposes?

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen anything saying *never* use them. Most of the time it is recommended to avoid them, simply because they often act as a crutch and can introduce unwanted side effects. However, when trying to introduce values into an observable stream, there is often no other way. The above method of wrapping it is a good pattern for using Subjects that should limit abuse.

Comment: Usually use of a `Subject` is an indication that the problem has not been thought all the way through.  In the OP case, what event is causing "somewhere else" to decide to emit a `user created` message?  Usually if you trace the problem all the way through, you'll find that you can push the problem all the way to a process boundary (e.g. network call, UI event, etc) and you can construct a long observable chain that starts with `Observable.Create` or `Observable.FromEvent` and flows all the way through without ever actually making a `Subject`.  At any rate, a `Subject` is a good place to start